# Angular JS, search/filter by many fields on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to implement this code I found into my application : http://jsfiddle.net/8PEAx/42/

With no success.  The demo actually works on my site but if I ammend it to suit my app it gives with the error when searching 'angular.lowercase(...).indexOf is not a function'

Please see my sample code below:

html:

```
<p><label>filter</label><input data-ng-model="phoneFilter.$" type="text">  </p>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:phoneFilter:multipleChoicesComparator">
        {{customer.name }} {{customer.lastname}}
    </li>
</ul>
                    </p>
```

Controller:

```
var CustomerController = function ($scope, customerService, $log, $routeParams, $location, $sce) {
    var customer = function (data) {
        $scope.Customer = data;
        $log.info(data);

    };

 $scope.multipleChoicesComparator = function (expected, actualInCompactForm)
    {
    var listActual = actualInCompactForm.split(' ');
    var mustBeIncluded = false;

    angular.forEach(listActual, function (actual)
    {
       if (angular.lowercase(expected).indexOf(angular.lowercase(actual)) !== -1)
        {
            mustBeIncluded = true;
        }
    });

    return mustBeIncluded;

    };
```

Can anyone assist.  The example just seems to search random input in any order and produce results.  Am I even to add a src to my html to cater for this new function?

Comment: Hey I am pretty new to this, I am sure you are being clear but how would I do this?

Comment: You have a capital c in `$scope.Customer`. The variables are case sensitive.  Essentially whatever is `$scope.VariableName`, variable name should be as is in the HTML page.

Comment: Your controller code also has no data being added to `$scope.Customers`. How are you adding data to that variable? Are you calling that function?

Comment: Hey it is a function, it calls a service and returns the data. this  is the code in the service.                                                                              var customer = function () {
            if (cachedCustomer)
                return $q.when(cachedCustomer);

            return $http.get("localhost:8080/api/customer")
                        .then(function (serviceResp) {
                            cachedCustomer = serviceResp.data;
                            return serviceResp.data;
                        });
        };